# Include an image to the right of a cell in Excel in Java using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Anyways wherein one can shift the image to the right of the cell in excel through java using poi. Tried all possible anchor position and co-ordinates but the image stays to the left side of the cell this

[image: Actual]

But required position is

[image: Expected]

Following is the code used to draw image to excel in java :-

```
private static void drawImageOnExcelSheet(XSSFSheet sheet, int row, int col, int height, int width, int pictureIdx)
        throws Exception {

    CreationHelper helper = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

    Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

    ClientAnchor anchor1 = helper.createClientAnchor();
    anchor1.setAnchorType(AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

    anchor1.setRow2(row); // second anchor determines bottom right position
    anchor1.setCol2(col);
    anchor1.setDx2(Units.toEMU(width)); // dx = left + wanted width
    anchor1.setDy2(Units.toEMU(height)); // dy= top + wanted height

    Picture pic = drawing.createPicture(anchor1, pictureIdx);
    pic.resize();

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `dx1(), dy1(), dx2(), dy2()` ?

Comment: Yes but still it remains at the left side only. Also I am not sure about the co-ordinates to be used within the same cell.

Comment: For placing something on right side of the cell, you need to know the width of the cell (column). Then the `Dx2` must be set `.setDx2(Units.toEMU(widthOfCellInPoints))` or `.setDx2(Units.pixelToEMU(widthOfCellInPixels))`.

Comment: Axel, tried the option you suggested as follows 

drawImageOnExcelSheet((XSSFSheet) sheet, row, i, 40, sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(i), pictureIdx1);

and setting to the anchor is as follows:

anchor1.setRow2(row); 
anchor1.setCol2(col);
anchor1.setDx2(Units.pixelToEMU((int) width));   anchor1.setDy2(Units.toEMU(height)); 

Picture pic = drawing.createPicture(anchor1, pictureIdx);
pic.resize();

But it doesn't work. Do I have to set any other position other than x2?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the code you are showing here is taken from this answer: [on adding image and text in same cell in excel using poi then image override the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325714/on-addding-image-and-text-in-same-cell-in-excel-using-poi-then-image-override-th/44330012#44330012). Your code has the same comments as my code in this answer. This leads to this suspicion.

In the answer you will find clearly described how anchors working to anchoring pictures which hovers in a layer over the cells.

For placing something on right side of the cell, you need to know the width of the cell (column). Then the dx of the second anchor must be set to the same amount as the cell width. Because the dx will be added to the column's position to determine the final position it will then be on right edge of the cell.

But for sure you will need a two cell anchor and so you should **not** do `pic.resize()` since the two cell anchor determines the size already.

Example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor.AnchorType;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

public class ExcelDrawImagesOnCell {

 private static void drawImageOnExcelSheet(XSSFSheet sheet, int row, int col, 
  int picHeight/*in px*/, int picWidth/*in px*/, int pictureIdx, boolean right) throws Exception {

  CreationHelper helper = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

  ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

  int columWidthInPx = Math.round(sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(col));

  anchor.setCol1(col); //first anchor determines upper left position
  anchor.setRow1(row);
  if (right) {
   anchor.setDx1(Units.pixelToEMU(columWidthInPx) - Units.pixelToEMU(picWidth)); //dx = right - wanted width
   anchor.setDy1(0); //dy = top
  } else {
   anchor.setDx1(0); //dx = left
   anchor.setDy1(0); //dy = top
  }

  anchor.setCol2(col); //second anchor determines bottom right position
  anchor.setRow2(row); 
  if (right) {
   anchor.setDx2(Units.pixelToEMU(columWidthInPx)); //dx = right
   anchor.setDy2(Units.pixelToEMU(picHeight)); //dy = top + wanted height
  } else {
   anchor.setDx2(Units.pixelToEMU(picWidth)); //dx = left + wanted width
   anchor.setDy2(Units.pixelToEMU(picHeight)); //dy = top + wanted height
  }

  drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

  InputStream is = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
  int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
  is.close();

  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 15*256); //set the column width to 15 character widths
  for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++ ) {
   sheet.createRow(r).createCell(1).setCellValue("Picture " + (r+1));
   //drawImageOnExcelSheet((XSSFSheet)sheet, r, 1, 16/*px*/, 16/*px*/, pictureIdx, false);
   drawImageOnExcelSheet((XSSFSheet)sheet, r, 1, 16/*px*/, 16/*px*/, pictureIdx, true/*right*/);
  }

  wb.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelDrawImagesOnCell.xlsx"));
  wb.close();
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Supplement May 14, 2018:

Having a solution using `XSSF` as well as `HSSF` for this is complicated because of the different strange measurement units which Microsoft is using and the fact that the binary file system `BIFF` `*.xls` and the `Office Open XML`  `*.xlsx` are very different not only in file storing but in general approaches also. In my answer in [apache poi XSSFClientAnchor not positioning picture with respect to dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567203/apache-poi-xssfclientanchor-not-positioning-picture-with-respect-to-dx1-dy1-dx/48607117#48607117) I have described that problem already.

So following code should work with both, `XSSF`as well as `HSSF`. It is commented where it uses special approaches. In general the values of `dx` and `dy` in `BIFF` are defined in [2.5.193 OfficeArtClientAnchorSheet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/fd656a2c-d5ee-4171-8f65-17a08b9f2262).

`dx`: The value is expressed as 1024th’s of that cell’s width.

`dy`: The value is expressed as 256th’s of that cell’s height.

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor.AnchorType;
import org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

public class ExcelDrawImagesOnCell {

 private static void drawImageOnExcelSheet(Sheet sheet, int row, int col, 
  int picHeight/*in px*/, int picWidth/*in px*/, int pictureIdx, boolean right) throws Exception {

  Row rowObject = sheet.getRow(row);
  if (rowObject == null) rowObject = sheet.createRow(row);
  float rowHeight = rowObject.getHeightInPoints();
  int rowHeightPx = Units.pointsToPixel(rowHeight);

  int columWidthInPx = Math.round(sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(col));
  
  CreationHelper helper = sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

  Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

  ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
  anchor.setAnchorType(AnchorType.MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

  anchor.setCol1(col); //first anchor determines upper left position
  anchor.setRow1(row);
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   if (right) {
    anchor.setDx1(Units.pixelToEMU(columWidthInPx) - Units.pixelToEMU(picWidth)); //dx = right - wanted width
    anchor.setDy1(0); //dy = top
   } else {
    anchor.setDx1(0); //dx = left
    anchor.setDy1(0); //dy = top
   }
  } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
   if (right) {
    anchor.setDx1((int)Math.round((columWidthInPx - picWidth) * 1024f / columWidthInPx)); //dx = right - wanted width
    anchor.setDy1(0); //dy = top
   } else {
    anchor.setDx1(0); //dx = left
    anchor.setDy1(0); //dy = top
   }
  }

  anchor.setCol2(col); //second anchor determines bottom right position
  anchor.setRow2(row); 
  if (sheet instanceof XSSFSheet) {
   if (right) {
    anchor.setDx2(Units.pixelToEMU(columWidthInPx)); //dx = right
    anchor.setDy2(Units.pixelToEMU(picHeight)); //dy = top + wanted height
   } else {
    anchor.setDx2(Units.pixelToEMU(picWidth)); //dx = left + wanted width
    anchor.setDy2(Units.pixelToEMU(picHeight)); //dy = top + wanted height
   }
  } else if (sheet instanceof HSSFSheet) {
   if (right) {
    anchor.setDx2((int)Math.round(columWidthInPx * 1024f / columWidthInPx)); //dx = right
    anchor.setDy2((int)Math.round(picHeight * 256 / rowHeightPx)); //dy = top + wanted height
   } else {
    anchor.setDx2((int)Math.round(picWidth * 1024f / columWidthInPx)); //dx = left + wanted width
    anchor.setDy2((int)Math.round(picHeight * 256 / rowHeightPx)); //dy = top + wanted height
   }
  }

  drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  //Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

  InputStream is = new FileInputStream("samplePict.jpeg");
  byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
  int pictureIdx = wb.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
  is.close();

  sheet.setColumnWidth(1, 20*256); //set the column width to 20 character widths
  for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++ ) {
   sheet.createRow(r).createCell(1).setCellValue("    Picture " + (r+1));
   if ((r % 2) == 0) {
    drawImageOnExcelSheet(sheet, r, 1, 16/*px*/, 16/*px*/, pictureIdx, false);
   } else {
    drawImageOnExcelSheet(sheet, r, 1, 16/*px*/, 16/*px*/, pictureIdx, true/*right*/);
   }
  }

  if (wb instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   wb.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelDrawImagesOnCell.xlsx"));
  } else if (wb instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   wb.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelDrawImagesOnCell.xls"));
  }
  wb.close();
 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Axel I have one more question. I am working with HSSFWorkbook wherein Units.pixelToEMU doesn't work and also I have sheet.getColumnWidth and not width in pixels. How should I deal with the unit conversion in this case and what standard unit should I use ?.

Comment: @viji shetty: See my supplement.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Axel. It was really a great help.